# EasySlider and CSS not playing nicely

Tags: html, css, easyslider

I'm just wondering if you can tell me why the slider at [www2.chrislrobinson.co.uk](http://www2.chrislrobinson.co.uk) doesn't work properly. I've lifted the code from their examples. It seems to work fine when the page first loads, but if you refresh, the image is stretched all across the page and it is very thin (i.e. height and width get screwed up).

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">  
...
<div id="mainContent">
...
    <div id="slider"> 
        <ul>                
            <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/30"><img src="images/01.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/7"><img src="images/02.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/25"><img src="images/03.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/26"><img src="images/04.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/27"><img src="images/05.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>          
        </ul> 
    </div>
```

and the paraphrased CSS:

```
#slider ul,  #slider li{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}   

#slider,  #slider li{ 
width:696px;
height:241px;
overflow:hidden; 
}

body  {
font: 100% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background: #000000 url('images/bg.png') no-repeat top center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#container { 
width: 804px;  /* this will create a container 80% of the browser width */
background: transparent;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left; /* this overrides the text-align: center on the body element. */
/*border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);*/
} 

#mainContent {
background: rgba(60,60,60,0.75) no-repeat top center;
width: 800px; 
border: 2px solid rgba(184,0,31,1); 
padding: 0px;
min-height: 600px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px; 
-khtml-border-radius: 10px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
min-height: 400px;
clear: both;
} 

span#prevBtn{}

span#nextBtn{}
```

Thanks!
Chris

**EDIT:**
If you keep refreshing it, it eventually works again for a bit! But that's not really a solution...

**EDIT 2:**
I found out that when it displays weirdly, this is the HTML:
`<div id="slider" style="width: 953px; height: 18px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; ">`
Anyone know why this might be changing?

Comment: You want your slider to be the same width as your #mainContent?

Comment: OR do you want the slider to be centered within the #mainContent div? I think i have a solution just need to know what your intention is.

Comment: At the minute the alignment isn't too important. I'm just wondering why even though I set the size to be 600x200, when it's run, the size is some random value. (953x18). I've fixed it at the minute by hard coding the values in the JS file as suggested here http://forum.jquery.com/topic/easyslider-problems-help

Answer (score 0):

I viewed your source and the first thing I would recommend is using a [Reset Styleshee](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)t or `* {margin:0;padding:0}` this will reset all your css properties across all browsers.

Then on `#slider, #slider li` add.

```
 #slider, #slider li {width:600px;height:200px}
```

This should help you achieve your goal.

**Edit:** And if you want to center your slideshow add

```
{margin:0 auto}
```